# How to create Cross Domain XMLHTTPRequests in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

My code looks like this, which is recommended for IE to work, but it only works in Chrome and FF. Is there a correct way to access a url from another domain. Furthermore, the domain is a domain I own and can allow access to the scripts trying to access it:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function sendRequest(url,callback,postData) {
    var req = createXMLHTTPObject();
    if (!req) return;
    var method = (postData) ? "POST" : "GET";
    req.open(method,url,true);
    req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent','XMLHTTP/1.0');
    if (postData)
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState != 4) return;
        if (req.status != 200 && req.status != 304) {
//          alert('HTTP error ' + req.status);
            return;
        }
        callback(req);
    }
    if (req.readyState == 4) return;
    req.send(postData);
}

var XMLHttpFactories = [
    function () {return new XMLHttpRequest()},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Msxml3.XMLHTTP")},
    function () {return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")}
];

function createXMLHTTPObject() {
    var xmlhttp = false;
    for (var i=0;i<XMLHttpFactories.length;i++) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = XMLHttpFactories[i]();
        }
        catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

function handleRequest(req) {
    var MyResponse = req.responseText;
    document.open();
    document.write(MyResponse);
    document.close();
}

 sendRequest("http://anotherdomain.com/urlwithcontentneeded.php",handleRequest);


</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's working in Chrome and Firefox? It shouldn't because of the same origin policy. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: the script on the domain has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin * - yes Chrome and FF both work, including Safari.

Answer (score 3):

IE does not suppoort cross domain requests in this way but does have a way using the XDomainRequest object instead, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx

It works in much the same way though, and yes it's a pain there are two ways to do it in different browsers

Comment: The following blog post has a createCORSRequest() function that works across all browsers that support CORS: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/